# I have a string in this format : 01/01 01:00:00

Tags: python, parsing, timestamp

I have a CSV file with Date/Time column and the entries in that column are in this fashion 01/01 01:00:00. How can i convert string to a timestamp? It gives an error saying hour must be in 0..23.I want to plot the datausing time series analysis.What is the best approach?

Comment: `01/01 01:00:00` there is no year, so there is no way to convert it into timestamp

Comment: What "gives an error"?

Comment: `datetime.datetime.strptime('01/01 01:00:00','%m/%d %H:%M:%S')` It will insert a default value for year.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify years you are able to use following

```
from datetime import datetime
x = datetime.strptime('01/01/2018 01:00:00','%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S').strftime("%s")
print(x)  # '1514761200'
```

`x` will be timestamp in seconds.